# Join 3rd Table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables that I need to join, I've been able to join two of them like this:

```
SELECT 
  coll.title AS CollectionTitle, 
  cont.CollectionID, 
  cont.title AS ContainerTitle, 
  cont.ID as ContainerID, 
  cont.LevelContainerID 
FROM tblCollections_Content cont 
JOIN  tblCollections_Collections coll 
  ON cont.collectionid = coll.id 
WHERE cont.title is NOT NULL 
ORDER BY CollectionID, ContainerID
```

However, I need to join this table as well `tblCollections_UserFields`, and need these to select these fields: `ContentID, Title, Value, EADElementID`; and join at the `ContentID` from this table at this point: `cont.collectionid=coll.id` (which is where the previous two tables are join).

Comment: Then whats the problem in joining the third table ?

Comment: the same as the second table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  coll.title AS CollectionTitle, 
  cont.CollectionID, 
  cont.title AS ContainerTitle, 
  cont.ID as ContainerID, 
  cont.LevelContainerID,
  cont.ContentID,
  user.Title,
  user.Value,
  user.EADElementID 
FROM tblCollections_Content cont 
JOIN  tblCollections_Collections coll 
  ON cont.collectionid = coll.id 
JOIN tblCollections_UserFields user
  ON cont.ContentId = user.ContentId
WHERE cont.title is NOT NULL 
ORDER BY CollectionID, ContainerID
```

I have to assume you have a ContentID column in your tblCollections_Content to join to your tblCollections_UserFields and that the columns you specified are all in the tblCollections_UserFields table.

Depending on the referential integrity of these tables you might need to use outer joins to see all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

simply add `JOIN anotherTable ON ...`